# Trying to get this earrings to move with a turbulence

Tags: animation

Do you know how to make the earrings move with a turbulence?
I only find tutorials for flags and ropes.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *Rigid Body Constraint*:

Create an empty between the head and the earring. Give *Rigid Body* passive and animated to the head, give *Rigid Body* active to the earring, give *Rigid Body Constraint* to the empty with *Type > Point* (or *Hinge*) and *Object First* > head, *Object Second* > earring. If you create a *Turbulence* force field here is what it gives:

[image]

You could also create a triangle, give it a *Cloth* simulation, pin its top vertex, parent the triangle to the head, parent the earring to the 3 vertices of the triangle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is so perfect!  Thank you so much!